# Why is the layer-aware debugging feature not stopping when entering function group include in filtered object set?

Tags: debugging, abap

i have specified the following object set in Debugger Layer config:

[image: Debugger Layer config]

The function module is called:

[image: calling point]

And yet the program stops at my next breakpoint I set in this function module to document the layer debugging isn't stopping:

[image: Stop in Line 213, not at the start. It's not the first statement eligible for setting a breakpoint if you're wondering that.]

Stop in Line 213, not at the start. It's not the first statement eligible for setting a breakpoint if you're wondering that.

Anybody have any insight to why this is not working?

Comment: Does the function module call maybe start a new internal mode and it is therefore not triggering?

Comment: How do you initiate call of FM? What is the calling program of tcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't say that you used the very important **"NEXT OBJECT SET"** button, I guess that's the reason why it didn't work.

[image: "Next object set" button in the debugger]

Credits : reference and screenshot taken from https://blogs.sap.com/2010/07/27/layer-aware-debugging-in-nw-70-ehp2/

Comment: Embarassingly enough, this is exactly it. *facepalm* Thanks a lot!